# Note number using aseqdump on my midi controller varies

Tags: linux, midi

I'm programming a Launchkey MK2 25 to control my Linux system. I've set up some key listeners for the white and black keys to perform some actions.

This works. The problem is that sometimes the first (white) key will be 48, or 51, or maybe something else. I thought it was the Octave setting, so I decided to just keep that at 0. The thing is it just changed again, from 51 to 48. Octave at 0. If I move the octave to 1, the first key is 60. If I move the octave to -1, the first key is 36.

I've been moving knobs and sliders to check if that could be affecting the note number offset but to no avail. Any idea what this could be? Also, would using `amidi` yield more consistent results?

I'm using:

```
aseqdump -p "Launchkey MK2 25"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem was actually with the configuration within the Launchkey, it was not a software problem. If you press both Octave buttons at the same time you can change the note offset, for instance so it starts on 49, or 50, or 51. So I configured it to start at 50.